# PCA transformation of xarray.Dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, python-xarray

I need to apply a PCA conversion to some Landsat (satellite imagery) scenes stored as xarray.Dataset and containing nan values (for technical reason each band of a given pixel will be nan).

Here is the code to create an example dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Create a demo xarray.Dataset
ncols = 25
nrows = 50

lon = [50 + x * 0.2 for x in range(nrows)]
lat = [30 + x * 0.2 for x in range(ncols)]
red = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) * 10000
green = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) * 10000
blue = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) * 10000
nir = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) * 10000
swir1 = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) * 10000
swir2 = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols) * 10000

ds = xr.Dataset({'red': (['longitude', 'latitude'], red),
                 'green': (['longitude', 'latitude'], green),
                 'blue': (['longitude', 'latitude'], blue),
                 'nir': (['longitude', 'latitude'], nir),
                 'swir1': (['longitude', 'latitude'], swir1),
                 'swir2': (['longitude', 'latitude'], swir2)},
                coords = {'longitude': (['longitude'], lon),
                          'latitude': (['latitude'], lat)})

# To keep example realistic let's add some nodata
ds = ds.where(ds.latitude + ds.longitude < 90)
print(ds)

<xarray.Dataset> Dimensions:    (latitude: 25, longitude: 50) Coordinates:   * longitude  (longitude) float64 50.0 50.2 50.4 50.6
50.8 51.0 51.2 51.4 ...   * latitude   (latitude) float64 30.0 30.2 30.4 30.6 30.8 31.0 31.2 31.4 ... Data variables:
    red        (longitude, latitude) float64 6.07e+03 13.8 9.682e+03 ...
    green      (longitude, latitude) float64 5.476e+03 350.4 7.556e+03 ...
    blue       (longitude, latitude) float64 4.306e+03 2.104e+03 9.267e+03 ...
    nir        (longitude, latitude) float64 1.445e+03 8.633e+03 6.388e+03 ...
    swir1      (longitude, latitude) float64 6.005e+03 7.692e+03 4.004e+03 ...
    swir2      (longitude, latitude) float64 8.235e+03 3.127e+03 674.6 ...
```

After a search on the internet, I tried unsuccessfully to implement sklearn.decomposition PCA functions.

I first convert each 2 dimensions band into a single dimension:

```
# flatten dataset
tmp_list = []
for b in ['red', 'green', 'blue','nir','swir1','swir2']:
    tmp_list.append(ds[b].values.flatten().astype('float64')) 
flat_ds = np.array(tmp_list)
```

Then I tried to compute PCA and transform the original data in a location without nan. I succeeded to generate some output but totally different than the one generated with ArcGIS or Grass.

When I changed my location it appeared sklearn function is not able to process data containing nan. So I removed nan values from the flattened dataset, which is problematic when I deflate the flattened PCA result as it does not contains a multiple of original dataset dimensions.

```
# deflate PCAs
dims = ds.dims['longitude'], ds.dims['latitude']
pcas = xr.Dataset()
for i in range(flat_pcas.shape[0]):
    pcas['PCA_%i' % (i + 1)] = xr.DataArray(np.reshape(flat_pcas[i], dims),
                                          coords=[ds.longitude.values, ds.latitude.values],
                                          dims=['longitude','latitude'])
```

To resume the situation:

- Does another simpler approach exist to implement PCA transformation on xarray.Dataset ?
- How to deal with nan ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `eofs`, available here: https://github.com/ajdawson/eofs

In the documentation they say:

> Transparent handling of missing values: missing values are removed automatically when computing EOFs and re-inserted into output fields.

I have used this a few times and I have found it very well-designed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the EOFs available from pycurrents (https://currents.soest.hawaii.edu/ocn_data_analysis/installation.html)

I have an example at https://github.com/manmeet3591/Miscellaneous/blob/master/EOF/global_sst.ipynb